# Pause/resume waypoint mission with DJI OSDK

Tags: linux, dji-sdk

I will describe you what I am looking for. Given a waypoint list I need the drone to go to a waypoint, pause the route to make other actions (transparent to the problem described here) and finally when the actions are done, resume the route to allow the drone going to the next waypoint of the list.

From what I have seen, the Mobile SDK provides tools for doing this. Has anybody found resources for doing this using only the **OSDK**? Any idea how it can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about OSDK. Personally, I am using ROS-OSDK and unfortunately, it is not possible to do what you are asking **out of the box**. But I managed to find some workarounds. Please keep in mind that ROS-OSDK is broadly based on OSDK. So what I am describing here can be done with plain OSDK (with more or less pain...).

You didn't specify what action you would like to do. So I will assume they are not drone-related (i.e. you don't want your drone to move during pause and actions will only involved third party sensors).

Second thing you didn't specify: how do you plan to send waypoints to your drone ? Are you willing to use OSDK or a third party application (like Altizure) ? If you go with first case, it will be easier. For the second, you will find a major problem that I came across : waypoints set from a third party are **NOT** broadcasted to OSDK once drone starts its mission. I managed to solve this issue, you can find my code [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/303#issuecomment-546339188). I just read it again, and it's pretty much plain OSDK (except I am in fact describing a ROS service).

Finally, you need some kind of mechanism to pause and restart mission. In ROS-OSDK, this is already implemented thanks to service `/dji_sdk/mission_waypoint_action`. The latter allows you to have control on the mission by simply using integers (i.e. "0" means start, "1" for stop, and so on. Please find documentation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/dji_sdk)).

So if we take a look at [ROS code describing this service](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/blob/fe32f40ae008ba62a668875c27ca5a312e62601b/dji_sdk/src/modules/dji_sdk_node_mission_services.cpp#L125-L159), we can see that the involved back-end functions are located in `vehicle->missionManager->wpMission` (of class `WaipointMission` in OSDK).

Hope that helps !